# Как лучше проверять наличие активной подписки у пользователя (laravel+vue)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt

Имеется SPA. Авторизация пользователя происходит через формирование JWT-токена и последующим хранением его в localstorage. У пользователя в базе есть поле, в котором стоит дата окончания подписки. Как лучше всего сделать проверку активной подписки? Пока, кроме, сохранения статуса подписки при логине в filestorage ничего в голову не приходит:

```
//laravel
    public function login(Request $request){
        ....
        $response['is_subscribed']=checkSubscribe($user->id);
        ....
    }


//vue
const mutations = {
LOGIN_USER (state, data) {
    ...
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
    localStorage.setItem('is_subscribed', data.is_subscribed)
    ...

},
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов, оно то понятно. Только как безопасно и правильно эту дату получить? При каждом обновлении страницы брать из базы, или при логине засунуть в localstorage и брать оттуда

Comment: В localStorage в браузере можно вручную изменять - так что не безопасно.

Comment: В любом случае при каждом запросе `axios` вы отправляете токен, по которому laravel ищет пользователя в БД и извлекает всю инфу о нем.